# iOS app with base 64 + hMac encoding

Tags: ios, encryption, base64

I use base64 + hMac to encode and decode the request & response of my app. When uploading the app do I have to say **YES** for;

> Does your product contain encryption?

Comment: Technically neither base64 nor HMAC are encryption. But I'm not sure what the "spirit" of this question entails.

Comment: @MikeWeller Exactly. I believe the Apple's question is due to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_in_the_United_States#US_export_rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should answer yes, but later you'll be given a choice that your product contains encryption only for integrity checking/auth/whatever else and you will not need to upload any cryptography export - related documents.